# Selenium - OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 'element not interactable

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to input text into a username field. It appears to find an element, however SendKeys() errors stating that the element is not interactable.  I'm already waiting until the element exists, so I wouldn't think its related to waiting.  Here is my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
ChromeDriver cd = new 
ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\");
cd.Url = @"https://connect.ramtrucks.com/us/en/login";
cd.Navigate();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(cd,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement e = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.ClassName("analytics-login-username")));

e.SendKeys("xxx@gmail.com");
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 thing you need to fix here:

1. You are using locator that is not unique.
2. You need to wait for element clickability, not just existence. I couldn't find element clickability case in C#, so element visibility can be used instead.
   So, instead of

```cs
IWebElement e = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.ClassName("analytics-login-username")));

e.SendKeys("xxx@gmail.com");
```

Try this:

```cs
IWebElement e = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("input.analytics-login-username"))).SendKeys("xxx@gmail.com");
```

Comment: Ahhh,  makes sense.  These changes worked.  Thank you so much!  I'm curious, how were you able to tell that locator wasn't unique?

Comment: The way to find locators is: open the page with Chrome, open dev tools with F12, Elements tab, use arrow to select elements. Control + F - write there the locator. It will show if such match exists and how many matches found. `analytics-login-username` class name will give you 2 matches while the first one is not the input you need, this element is not interactable. Simple.